# foreach can't work in server but in localhost work

Tags: laravel, foreach

I'm want upload my laravel project to 000webhost but i got an error with foreach ,how do i fix the error

view:

```php
    @foreach ($rvw as $rw)
        <div class="item">
            <div class="card-review">
                <div class="batas">
                    <img src="{{asset($rw->foto)}}" class="img-review">
                </div>
                <div class="batas2">
                    <span class="bio-review">{{$rw->nama}}</span>
                    <br>                        
                </div>
                <div class="batas3">
                    <p class="text-review">"{{$rw->ulasan}}"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

controller:

```php
       $index['idx'] = DB::table('index')->first();
       $index['albm'] = DB::table('album')->first();
       $index['rvw'] = DB::table('reviews')->get();

       return view('index',$index);
```

With error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   /storage/ssd4/813/10210813/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Comment: check what is the value in `$index['rvw']` before passing it to view. try doing `dd($index['rvw']);` and let us know what does it print?

Comment: or you may add `@if (count($rvw))` above for-each

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$idx  = DB::table('index')->get();
$albm = DB::table('album')->get();
$rvw  = DB::table('reviews')->get();
return view('index',compact('albm','rvm','idx'));
```

Comment: Check your database. See if the target has at least one record.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not iterate through index due to which there is an error.Use This code

```
@foreach ($index['rvw'] as $rw)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="card-review">
            <div class="batas">
                <img src="{{asset($rw->foto)}}" class="img-review">
            </div>
            <div class="batas2">
                <span class="bio-review">{{$rw->nama}}</span>
                <br>                        
            </div>
            <div class="batas3">
                <p class="text-review">"{{$rw->ulasan}}"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```